# Is it possible to install SSL on Google app engine for iPhone application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

I am using python language for google app engine based iphone application .I want to install/access ssl on python. I am unable to find a way to install/enable it in python file. please guide me how can I make my application to connect to ssl As I want to Apple enable push notification services on my application Its urgent.

Answer (score 5):

See the App Engine Python documentation on setting up [secure URLs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Secure_URLs). Note that this will only work when accessed via your appspot.com domain - it's not possible to have SSL on a custom domain through App Engine, currently.

Answer (score 0):

Nick Johnson has already provided a link and mentioned that this functionality is not currently available on your domain (only on apps running on Google's hotspot domain).

Obviously, most developers need their apps to run on their own domains, so this is a [very highly requested feature](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=792&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component).  Fortunately, Google has recently added this feature to [their GAE roadmap](http://code.google.com/intl/ko-KR/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) indicating that it will be available soon.  Unfortunately, we don't know what 'soon' means.